# Flutter: add Share Extension

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, bitcode, share-extension

### Problem

I have add iOS `Share Extension` into a very simple Flutter project,

[My code](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/Flutter-Share-Extension-Demo) setup with device on [feature branch](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/Flutter-Share-Extension-Demo/tree/dev/enable_share_extension_for_device), I also know [bitcode in flutter is not ready yet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15288):

#### Run `Target: Share Extension` on device

```
ld: '[Project_Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FMDB/libFMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)' 
does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting 
ENABLE_BITCODE)
```

#### Run `Target: The Container App` on device

NOTE: this `[CP] Embed Pods Framworks` is same as `[ProjectCompare]`.

```
* Run custom shell script '[CP] Embed Pods Framworks'....
* Validate [Project_Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphonos/Runner.app/PlugIns/
  ShareExtension.appe(in target: Runner)
* cd [Project_Path]/ios
* builtin-embeddedBinaryValidationUtility [Project_Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/
  Debug-iphonos/Runner.app/PlugIns/ShareExtension.appex 
    -siging-cert [someID] 
    -info-plist-path [Project_Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphonos/Runner.app/Info.plist
* error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. 
  Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.
    * Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    Not Code Signed
    * Parent App Signing Certificate:  iPhone Developer: MyName (XXXXX)
```

### To Compare

I also have create a pure iOS project [ProjectCompare](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/iOS-Share-Extension-Demo) too, and add `Pod` into it, after change. I open project with `workspace` and add `Share Extension`, it works well on device.

### Question

So I think maybe some script related to Flutter setup cause this error ? Or the script in [Podfile](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/Flutter-Share-Extension-Demo/blob/dev/enable_share_extension_for_device/ios/Podfile) ?

Any idea how to do?

### UPDATE

#### After overwrite setting in `Target: Share Extension`:

> - `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` = "";
> - `OTHER_LDFLAGS` = "";  or  `OTHER_LDFLAGS` = "-ObjC";

Run `Target: ShareExtension` & `Target: The Container App` on device both works.

Answer (score 2):

So with [@pulyaevskiy](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16712#issuecomment-423261438)'s help. I found the fix:

#### Short:

`overwrite` setting in `Target: Share Extension`: (git diff [sample](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/Flutter-Share-Extension-Demo/pull/1/commits/0e9d719f41ae21f558de34f9224f00aae9b68cd4))

> `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` = "";
>
> `OTHER_LDFLAGS` = "";  or  `OTHER_LDFLAGS` = "-ObjC";

#### Detail:

1. Location: when run `Target: ShareExtension` & `Target: Container App`
   both get error, just because adding the `Target: Share Extension`.
   It means the error are mostly coming from `Target: ShareExtension`.
2. List the command details:

```
[Clang Path]/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot 
[iOS SDK Path]/iPhoneOS12.4.sdk 
-L[Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos 
-L[Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FMDB      <-- this 
-L[Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos/sqflite   <-- this 
-F[Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos 
-F[Project Path]/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/flutter/ios 
-filelist [Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/ShareExtension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ShareExtension.LinkFileList 
-Xlinker 
-rpath 
-Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks 
-Xlinker 
-rpath 
-Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks 
-Xlinker 
-rpath 
-Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks 
-Xlinker 
-rpath 
-Xlinker 
@executable_path/../../Frameworks 
-miphoneos-version-min=12.4 
-dead_strip 
-Xlinker 
-object_path_lto 
-Xlinker [Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/ShareExtension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ShareExtension_lto.o 
-Xlinker 
-export_dynamic 
-Xlinker 
-no_deduplicate 
-fembed-bitcode-marker 
-fobjc-arc 
-fobjc-link-runtime 
-fapplication-extension 
-ObjC 
-lFMDB              <-- this 
-lsqflite           <-- this 
-lsqlite3           <-- this 
-framework Flutter  <-- this 
-e _NSExtensionMain 
-Xlinker 
-dependency_info 
-Xlinker [Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/ShareExtension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ShareExtension_dependency_info.dat 
-o [Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ShareExtension.appex/ShareExtension
```

Error detail:

```
ld: '[Project_Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FMDB/libFMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)' 
does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting 
ENABLE_BITCODE)
```

3. So search `Target: ShareExtension`'s setting with `FMDB`, there's 3 result:

   > 1. `Other Linker Flags`:`-l"FMDB"`
   > 2. `Header Search Flags`:`"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FMDB"`
   > 3. `Library Search Flags`:`"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FMDB"`
4. `Library Search Flags` is the one like a path of `DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FMDB/libFMDB.a`, so I `overwrite` it with `""`, result in git diff is **add a new line:** `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "";`
5. Run `Target: ShareExtension` to check result: 
   These two line of command details are gone

```
-L[Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FMDB
-L[Project Path]/ios/DerivedData/Products/Debug-iphoneos/sqflite
```

Error become(which also means above change works):

```
ld: library not found for -lFMDB
```

4. Search `FMDB` again, and I guess the `Other Linker Flags`:`-l"FMDB"` are like the error of `-lFMDB`, so I `overwrite` it with `""`(or left `"-ObjC"`), result in git diff is **add a new line:** `OTHER_LDFLAGS = "";` or `OTHER_LDFLAGS = "-ObjC";`.
5. Run `Target: ShareExtension` & `Target: Container App` now both works.

Check [change in git differ](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/Flutter-Share-Extension-Demo/pull/1/commits/0e9d719f41ae21f558de34f9224f00aae9b68cd4)

[image]
[image]
[image]